# Ajax content indexing, Google

Tags: ajax, seo

I've followed the instructions from the Google website to enable Ajax crawling on my AngularJS site by adding the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

The rendered content has some links like:

```
<a href="/user/1">User 1</a>
<a href="/user/2">User 2</a>
<a href="/user/3">User 3</a>
```

Also some Ajax tabs which render dynamic content like:

```
<a href="#!/popular">Popular</a>
<a href="#!/recent">Recent</a>
```

Looking at the server logs, GoogleBot did came and passed in correctly the _escaped_fragement in the Uri, which is correct:

```
_escaped_fragment_=%2fpopular
_escaped_fragment_=%2frecent
```

Problem is that looking at actual indexed content using site:www.somesite.com and logs on server, I see that GoogleBot attempted to index pages like:

```
/user/1/#!/popular
/user/1/#!/recent
```

Why would something like this happen considering those urls are relative and don't have #! on them to indicate ajax content and is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those URLs are available on all pages, it will simply add them.

So, if I would go to: `<a href="/user/1">User 1</a>` and there are again `<a href="#!/popular">Popular</a>` there pages, then it's logical that Google loads: `/user/1#!/popular`

You might want to know that I've solved this puzzle with a script that's on Github: https://github.com/kubrickology/Logical-escaped_fragment

Simply build your AJAX pages with: `__init()`

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't this search https://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://kubrickolo.gy/SEO-AJAX-example&hl=en supposed to return some results?

Comment: No, because I have a robots.txt in there. Why, now idea :-P
I'll change that